# Implement html onkeyup and onkeydown on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, events, onkeyup, onkeydown

What is equivalent to onkeyup and onkeydown event listeners for html page on UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible as there is no physical keyboard.

Here is some additional information on the topic

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2007/08/02/safari-on-the-iphone-2-steps-forward-1-step-back/

Comment: tanks, I have seen touchup touchdown i don't know yet how exactly to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while developing a mobile website, I used the onKeyPress event with success, have you tried it?